# How to use custom sorter in XML views

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have the following list, using a custom sorter:

```js
var oTemplate = ... // irrelevant

var oList = new sap.m.List({
    id: this.createId("someList"),
    items: {
        path: "/list",
        template: oTemplate,
        sorter: foo.bar.CustomSorter
    }
});
```

How can I use the custom sorter in XML views?
Based on the answer at "[Data-binding does not work in XML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156603/data-binding-does-not-work-in-xml-view)", I tried following, but it didn't work:

```xml
<m:List id="someList"
        items="{
            path: '/list',
            sorter: 'foo.bar.CustomSorter'
        }">
    <!-- hid ListItem implementation -->
</m:List>
```

Removing the quotes around the sorter doesn't also work:

```xml
...
            sorter: foo.bar.CustomSorter
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged BindingParser and seems like "formatter", "factory" and "groupHeaderFactory" resolve as reference as you want but "filters" and "sorters" resolve as a static object.
So in xml binding this is not supported you should open feature request https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: Ok, I see it is not possible in this way. But how to do that? Setting the sorter on the controller? Can you check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104339/how-to-set-sorter-of-a-list-in-controller-in-sapui5